# What is the Vault option in BrainTree payment methods in Magento 2?

Tags: e-commerce, braintree, magento2

What is the Vault option in Magento 2 and how does it work? I looked at the BrainTree documentation but did not find anything related to it. Is is feature of Magento 2 or BrainTree?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The Vault option is a Braintree feature which Magento has integrated. The Braintree Vault allows a merchant to store a customer's payment information and charge that customer, so that a customer does not need to enter their payment information multiple times.  For more information on the Braintree Vault, check out this [documentation](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/vault/overview).

When using the Braintree Vault within Magento, be sure to set `Enable Vault` to `Yes`. For more information on configuration, check out this Magento [documentation](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/payment/braintree-setup.html).

Comment: So, the Vault saves some kind of ID in magento but the actual details are stored in BrainTree. Or are the customer details stored in Magento itself?

Comment: Why is the Vault visible when Braintree is disabled? Other payment methods may have their own saved card sections, having a saved card section visible when the actual payment method is disabled is very confusing to the customer.